# Creating button from Standard Controller Visualforce page with constructor issue

Tags: apex, visualforce, callout

So I am trying to create a custom button to open a visualforce page but I'm having issues calling the apex class.

I'm getting the following error:  *common.apex.runtime.bytecode.BytecodeApexObjectType cannot be cast to common.apex.runtime.impl.ApexType*

Here is my Class:

```
public class APM_OpenChart {
    private ApexPages.StandardController controller;    
    public APM_OpenChart(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {
        controller = stdController;
    }

    public PageReference openChart()
    {
        return Page.chart1;
    }    
}
```

Here is the visualforce page string to extend to that class:

```
<apex:page standardController="APM__c" extensions="APM_OpenChart" id="pgid" recordSetVar="apps">
    <apex:form>
        <apex:pageblock mode="edit" id="yearPageBlock">
            <apex:pageBlockButtons>
                <apex:commandButton action="{!openChart}" value="OpenChart"/>
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
```

Am I calling this apex class incorrectly?  The error is happening on line 0 of my VF page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you're passing in a recordsetvar

Try changing your controller to:

```
public class APM_OpenChart {
private ApexPages.StandardSetController controller;    
public APM_OpenChart(ApexPages.StandardSetController controller) {
    this.controller = controller;
}

public PageReference openChart()
{
    return Page.chart1;
}
```

Comment: we posted at the exact same time!  Perfect answer

Answer (score 2):

I guess I needed to use a Standard**Set**Controller.  The blank constructor worked.

```
public class APM_OpenChart {

    public APM_OpenChart(ApexPages.StandardSetController stdController) {

    }

    public PageReference openChart()
    {
        return Page.chart1;
    }    
}
```